# How to read specific Json object from Json string in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Following is the `JSON` string:

```
{
"ios_info": {
    "serialNumber": "F2LLMBNJFFF",
    "imeiNumber": "01388400413235",
    "meid": "",
    "iccID": "8901410427640096045",
    "firstUnbrickDate": "11/27/13",
    "lastUnbrickDate": "11/27/13",
    "unbricked": "true",
    "unlocked": "false",
    "productVersion": "7.1.2",
    "initialActivationPolicyID": "23",
    "initialActivationPolicyDetails": "US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy",
    "appliedActivationPolicyID": "23",
    "appliedActivationDetails": "US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy",
    "nextTetherPolicyID": "23",
    "nextTetherPolicyDetails": "US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy",
    "macAddress": "ACFDEC6C988A",
    "bluetoothMacAddress": "AC:FD:EC:6C:98:8B",
    "partDescription": "IPHONE 5S SPACE GRAY 64GB-USA"
},
"fmi": {
    "@attributes": {
        "version": "1",
        "deviceCount": "1"
    },
    "fmipLockStatusDevice": {
        "@attributes": {
            "serial": "F2LLMBNJFFFQ",
            "imei": "013884004132355",
            "isLocked": "true",
            "isLost": "false"
        }
    }
},
"product_info": {
    "serialNumber": "F2LLMBNJFFFQ",
    "warrantyStatus": "Apple Limited Warranty",
    "coverageEndDate": "11/25/14",
    "coverageStartDate": "11/26/13",
    "daysRemaining": "498",
    "estimatedPurchaseDate": "11/26/13",
    "purchaseCountry": "United States",
    "registrationDate": "11/26/13",
    "imageURL": "http://service.info.apple.com/parts/service_parts/na.gif",
    "explodedViewURL": "http://service.info.apple.com/manuals-ssol.html",
    "manualURL": "http://service.info.apple.com/manuals-ssol.html",
    "productDescription": "iPhone 5S",
    "configDescription": "IPHONE 5S GRAY 64GB GSM",
    "slaGroupDescription": "",
    "contractCoverageEndDate": "11/25/15",
    "contractCoverageStartDate": "11/26/13",
    "contractType": "C1",
    "laborCovered": "Y",
    "limitedWarranty": "Y",
    "partCovered": "Y",
    "notes": "Covered by AppleCare+ - Incidents Available",
    "acPlusFlag": "Y",
    "consumerLawInfo": {
        "serviceType": "",
        "popMandatory": "",
        "allowedPartType": ""
    }
}
}
```

Following **Reads ALL**`JSON` in `Key:Value` and displays in table format But i need only specific object i.e **FMI** **section** of json string only:

```
private string GetKeyValuePairs(string jsonString)
    {
        var resDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
        string sdict = string.Empty;
        string fmitxt = string.Empty;
        string fmitxt2 = string.Empty;
        foreach (string key in resDict.Keys)
        {
          sdict += "<tr><td> " + key + "</td> " + (resDict[key].GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) ? "<td>" + GetKeyValuePairs(resDict[key].ToString()) + "</td></tr>" : "<td>" + resDict[key].ToString() + "</td></tr>");

        }
        return sdict;
    }
```

**Problem:**

I want to **read ALL the content of "fmi" section only**. and display in **key:Value.** table format

**NOTE:** 
I am using *Framework 3.5* hence cant use `dynamic` keyword.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you work with it as a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) directly; this is the class you'd be using behind-the-scenes if you were using `dynamic`. Also, you need to separate out the selection of `fmi` from the normal path done in the recursive calls: here I have it in `Main`.

```
void Main()
{
    var resObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
    var result = GetKeyValuePairs((JObject)resObj["fmi"]);
}
private string GetKeyValuePairs(JObject resObj)
{
    string sDict = string.Empty;
    string fmitxt = string.Empty;
    string fmitxt2 = string.Empty;
    foreach (var pair in resObj)
    {
      sDict += "<tr><td> " + pair.Key + "</td>";
      if (pair.Value is JObject)
        sDict += "<td>" + GetKeyValuePairs((JObject)pair.Value) + "</td></tr>";
      else
        sDict += "<td>" + pair.Value.ToString() + "</td></tr>";
    }
    return sDict;
}
```

Comment: What is the word "Dump()" is it a keyword in 3.5? I am not getting your code! Throws error! :(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Oops, that was a thing from my debugging/developing in LINQPad. It just let me see the results of that method call. You can remove it.

Comment: Hey @Tim S! you are simply great..! :) It works! after modifying at certain extent :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not deserializing this into a "strong typed" object you can do something like this:

```
    var fmi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(str)["fmi"];
    var keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(fmi.ToString());
```

Comment: have u tried this? it gives error at line: resDict["fmi"].Keys. Error:Object does not contain defination for Keys. :(

Comment: Not in formatted way as i need! but still you deserve +1 and appreciate your time spending for me! :)

Comment: I would create a strong type object for the fmi section and deserialize the content into it. It's hard to work with dynamics\dictionaries\jsons in the current way.

Comment: Yes i agree! This approach i have choosen becoz the JSON string contents may vary. First i have used the JSON to C# Class converter but  the JSON fails to compile so...:)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved accurately with this method, just keep in mind, you will need Newtonsoft.Json;

```cs
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
// using System.IO;

string dataPath = @"myfile.json"; // Location of the json
string jsonData = "";
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(dataPath)))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    jsonData = json;
}
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
string value = obj["name"]; // here name is the object name holding the required data
Console.WriteLine(value);
Console.ReadLine();
/*
* OUTPUT
* itzplayz
*/
```

**Here's the JSON Example**

```json
{
  "name": "itzplayz"
}
```

Now you can get the value of the JSON object in the string called value